# Tradução de "about" junto da tag

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tradução, localização

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Falta traduzir o link "about" que está na página de cada tag.

Talvez "***acerca***" seja uma boa tradução?

Comment: "Sobre" funciona em português português? Em "brasileiro" soa melhor.

Comment: @bfavaretto "Sobre" funciona bem em pt_PT também.

Comment: Que bom! Porque os espanhóis acham que "sobre" é "guardanapo", hehehe!

Comment: @bfav, guardanapo é *servilleta*, *sobre* é envelope :P E pra ajudar na memorização, em francês é *serviette* d:p