# Encontrar comentário feito

Tags: suporte, comentários

É possível localizar algum comentário feito por um usuário (eu no caso) de forma mais fácil ou eficaz do que ficar caçando ele pelo registro de atividades?

Recentemente houve um tópico no qual eu postei um comentário com um link pro JSFiddle com um sistema bem, mas bem simples, de slides, com três `<figure>`, três `<figcaption>` e dois botoes de avançar e retroceder (vai que alguém acha...).

Eu sei que o tópico não foi respondido nem comentado por ninguém depois de mim porque não recebi nenhuma notificação, mas também não sei se o tópico foi deletado o que justificaria eu não encontrá-lo no registro de Atividades.

E como eu fiquei um certo tempo na lógica da ação dos botões, eu queria saber se tem como eu ter acesso à esse link, desse comentário.

Comment: Não tem jeito muito melhor de procurar comentários, é um ponto fraco do sistema. É [este](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40593/como-posso-incorporar-textos-e-retornar-da-%c3%baltima-at%c3%a9-a-primeira-imagem-do-slide#comment79888_40593)?

Comment: Esse mesmo. E embora o Google não tenha ajudado, o Data Explorer sugerido pelo Bacco não só ajudou como trouxe o resultado como primeiro da lista.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Não há um recurso próprio para isto já pronto na UI padrão do site, mas uma boa alternativa é usar o [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/help) para fazer a busca.

Eis uma query que faz uma busca pelo ID do usuário e por uma palavra chave:

```
SELECT
   CreationDate,
   Id [Comment Link],
   postID [Post Link],
   Score
FROM 
   Comments
WHERE
   UserId = ##UserId## AND
   Text LIKE '%##String##%'
ORDER BY
   CreationDate DESC;
```

Para acessá-la pronta para usar, clique no link abaixo e preencha os parâmetros com seu ID e a *string* desejada.

► **[Find words / strings in comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/250494/)**

Se desejar procurar aqui no Meta em vez do site principal, basta clicar no *checkbox* "switch sites", ou selecionar outro dos sites da SE logo em seguida (lembrando de atualizar o ID de usuário, que muda em cada um dos sites principais).

**Observação1**: o ID do usuário pode ser visto no URL do respectivo perfil, **e é diferente em cada site + meta** da rede:

```
http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco
                                       └────────── neste caso, o ID é 70
```

**Observação2**: no FAQ do *Data Explorer* consta o seguinte:

> The data is updated early every Monday morning around 3:00 UTC.

Ou seja, a atualização e respectiva disponibilização dos dados novos ocorre às segundas-feiras de madrugada, portanto, usualmente não dá localizar os comentários mais recentes.

Comment: Danado.... Foi o primeiro resultado da query. Valeu :D

Answer (score 4):

Também é possível usar o Google, mas depende muito se você lembra de uma *palavra-chave específica* que escreveu (ou leu) no comentário.

Por exemplo, sei que escrevi um comentário aqui no Meta e que continha a palavra "guardanapo", então usando a seguinte *query* no Google:

```
guardanapo site:meta.pt.stackoverflow.com
```

O [único resultado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2032/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-about-junto-da-tag#comment6334_2032) é:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: O engraçado foi que eu tentei e o resultado em particular que eu esperava encontrar não apareceu.

Comment: Pode não ter funcionado para achar comentários aqui, mas agora eu sei usar melhor o Google :) +1